# How to judge whether a dependency is in the Relation?

Tags: database, relation

We have a relation R(A1, A2, A3, A4)
The table is
[image]
There are three functional dependencies :

```
a) A4 -> A1, 
b) {A2, A3} -> A4, 
c) {A2, A3} -> A1
```

which of them are dependencies in R?

Comment: What do you mean by "are hold"? ("Hold" isn't an adjective)

Comment: This looks like undergraduate database-theory homework: you can determine the answer immediately by applying the rules for the normalization level you're after. So... _assuming_ that you have applied the rules then what is your problem or question?

Comment: Only A4 can be the primary key, and {A2, A3} is not a super key. So, a is right?